# Laravel GET Route got 403 Forbidden in Plesk

Tags: laravel, plesk

I have route in my web.php

`https://sub.domain.com/auth/google/callback`

This is being call after user successfully login using google mail on my project.

[image]

The route is working on my local but when I upload it to plesk. It always says 403 forbidden page.

I tried to apply chmod -R 775 on my public and storage folder. However the site still getting the same error.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

This is my web.php

```
  // Authentication
  Route::get('/auth/{provider}/redirect', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'redirect'])
->where('provider', 'github|google');

   Route::get('/auth/{provider}/callback', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'callback'])
->where('provider', 'github|google');
```

I'm not using middleware on my web.php

Here's my .htaccess located at `sub.domain.com/.htaccess`

```
#<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 #  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 #  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 #
 #  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
 #  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
 #  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
 #  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 #  Header append Vary User-Agent
 #</IfModule>
 #
 ### EXPIRES CACHING ##
 #<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 #  ExpiresActive On
 #
 #  # Images
 #  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 #
 #  # Video
 #  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
 #  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
 #
 #  # CSS, JavaScript
 #  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 #
 #  # Others
 #  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
 #  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
 #</IfModule>
 ### EXPIRES CACHING ##

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

 #    # Force Https
 #    RewriteEngine On
 #    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 #    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 #
 #    # Force www
 #    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 #    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 </IfModule>

 # Check if mod is installed. If not, you can try to comment the condition
 <IfModule mod_php7.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
 php_value max_input_time 259200
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
 Options -Indexes
 </IfModule>
 <FilesMatch "^\.">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your route, especially middlewares

Comment: Currently. I'm using any middleware. Because it's in the web.php.

Comment: Maybe the problem arises from your .htaccess config file because it is a webserver error.

Comment: Hello, the code is working on my local. I dont think it's htaccess error.

Comment: Same situation for me here, did you solve the problem ? Thanks in advance @Pablo